# How to drop the first row in multi index dataframe for each group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset that looks like this:

[image]

In my data, each group [groupby place,zoneid,id] should start with [In] as the first event. So, I need to drop the first row in the group if it was [Out]

My attempt is as the following:

```
S=Data
for idx, group in Data.groupby(level='bayid'):
    if group ['Event'][0]=='Out':
        S= S.drop(data.index[0], axis=0)
```

But my data is too large. Is there is a faster way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
s = df.groupby(['Place','zoneid','Id']).head(1)
df = df.drop(s.index[s['Event']=='Out'])
```

Comment: Yeah, that is smart. Thanks a lot